# XSD node with mixed content that appears any number of times in any order

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm stuck on how to create and XSD that allows children of an 'objects' node be either 'text' or 'image' nodes any show up any number of times and in any order. The order in which they appear within the 'objects' node determines how they are rendered but the order does not need to be validated.

Example 1

```
<objects>
    <textobject x="30" y="100" value="blah1" />
    <imageobject x="0" y="0" src="/path/to/some/image1.png"/> 
    <imageobject x="0" y="0" src="/path/to/some/image2.png"/>
    <textobject x="60" y="250" value="blah2" />
    <textobject x="60" y="250" value="blah3" />
</objects>
```

Example 2

```
<objects> 
    <imageobject x="0" y="0" src="/path/to/some/image1.png"/>
    <textobject x="30" y="100" value="blah1" />
    <textobject x="60" y="250" value="blah2" />
    <imageobject x="0" y="0" src="/path/to/some/image2.png"/>
    <textobject x="60" y="250" value="blah3" />
</objects>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `xs:choice` with `minOccurs="0"` and `maxOccurs="unbounded"`:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="objects">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="imageobject"/>
        <xs:element ref="textobject"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="imageobject">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="src" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="x" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:attribute name="y" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="textobject">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="value" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="x" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:attribute name="y" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: thanks for that, this gave me:

Recoverable parse error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'imageobject' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
Recoverable parse error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'textobject' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
SAXException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'imageobject'. No child element is expected at this point.

Comment: The schema as supplied is valid - I tested it in Saxon. Perhaps you changed it in some way, e.g. by adding namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

In this situation it may well be appropriate to use a substitution group. Define "mediaObject" as an abstract element, with "textObject" and "imageObject" as members of its substitution group, and then define the content model as `<xs:element ref="mediaObject" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>`. The advantage of this design is that it's more extensible, it achieves separation of concerns, better expression of the semantics, and greater reusability of definitions. The benefits really start to show when there are 15 kinds of media object rather than two.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">`.